# Filtering out duplicate data based on more than one value in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, distinct

I have a simple table like so

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |      datetime       |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2019-05-05 16:00:00 |
|  1 | 2019-05-05 17:00:00 |
|  1 | 2019-05-05 18:00:00 |
|  1 | 2019-05-05 18:00:00 |
|  2 | 2019-05-05 16:00:00 |
|  2 | 2019-05-05 17:00:00 |
|  2 | 2019-05-05 18:00:00 |
|  3 | 2019-05-05 17:00:00 |
|  3 | 2019-05-05 17:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

I'd like to filter out all the rows with duplicate `datetime` entries for *each* `id`, so that I may end up with a table like this:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |      datetime       |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2019-05-05 16:00:00 |
|  1 | 2019-05-05 17:00:00 |
|  1 | 2019-05-05 18:00:00 |
|  2 | 2019-05-05 16:00:00 |
|  2 | 2019-05-05 17:00:00 |
|  2 | 2019-05-05 18:00:00 |
|  3 | 2019-05-05 17:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

What is the easiest way to do this in MySQL?

**EDIT**: Let's say I had another column called `weight` that assigns a numerical weight to each row of data. Is there a way to tell MySQL to filter out the duplicate `datetime` entries for each `id` based on which one has the largest `weight`?

Comment: Without some mechanism for uniquely identifying rows, you don't really have a table.

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a different question (referring back to this one if appropriate)

Comment: like @Strawberry more or less saids there is no way to write a SQL which will grantantee 100% deterministic (fixed) results always without that uniquely identifying column which need to have a primary or unique key..

Comment: We can assume that that column exists, I'm just using a skeleton table to get a general idea of what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

use distinct

```
   select distinct id,datetime from table_name
```

after your edit it seems you need `row_number()`

```
 select * from 
  (select *,
  row_number() over(partition by id,datetime order by weight desc) rn
  from table_name
  ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: This query is wrong, look into the expected result it seams to be the "last" unique 3 records limit per group..  Also see mine comment under the question..

Comment: the example/expected data was not changed in the edit.. Also the edit is a "new" question..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.weight = (select max(t2.weight)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.datetime = t.datetime
                 );
```